# How does spring dependency injection work?

Tags: java, spring

I want to know  when are the dependencies injected in a spring bean.
I have the following code :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    // throws Null Pointer Here.
    String prop = env.getProperty("some.property");

    public void test() {
        // works here
        String prop = env.getProperty("some.property");
    }
}
```

Why does spring throws NPE when I try to get Environment variable.
What happens when the class constructor is called? Does spring only looks for bean availability in the context at construction time and not inject it then and there? Please explain the full flow of bean creation. Are the dependencies only injected after the object is constructed and added to the context? Does spring look for dependencies only after an instance of the class is created or does it look for them when the constructor is called?

Comment: Have you tried reading any documentation first? Or Spring In Action?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read by yourself about bean life cycle. There is a lot of nice graphs on Internet, but..
let me help you with this NPE.
What you are trying to do is set property before injection is finished.
Spring first makes instantion of object, then **populates fields** and after that makes injection. So... Your code at first creates fields (and tries to set them using env field) before your env field is initialized.
Method test() is call after the class object is fully created so env field is already correctly prepared for usage.

I hope that helps.